# Eclipse Neon searching for shared libraries in the root folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

I installed Eclipse Neon yesterday and it seemed to be working fine. Installed a few plug-ins and did some work.

Today when I start it I get the following error message:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/eclipse46
/root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

I found some references in the `config.ini` file to the `root` folder (I have no idea why). I have correct these and the file now looks like:

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.AgentImpl
#Tue Jul 26 16:10:00 CEST 2016
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=_opt_eclipse.neon_eclipse
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.102.v20160118-1700.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160606-1100
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.200.v20160504-1450.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
osgi.framework.extensions=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar,reference\:file\:org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension_1.0.0.v201605131737.jar
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
```

However, I am still getting the "permission denied" error. Is there any way of correcting this?

Comment: Did you use the Eclipse Installer? Usually, Eclipse is better being installed in the user home directory using regular user permissions.

Comment: Yes, I used the new Installer, which I never used before. I keep software insulated from user areas, especially since user home folders tend to be in different media.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put my user's folder to eclipse.ini file, and this didn't worked.

```
--launcher.library ~/.p2/pool/plugin /org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
```

seems the best approach for now is to copy the folder inside root home to your user, once its create with the the new installer.